# Find last activity date without scrolling through answers?

Tags: support, dates, last-activity

When I arrive at a question or answer from another question's link I am not able to see the **activity datestamp** that is shown had I otherwise found the question in the *Questions* list.

I've had to scroll through all the answers looking at each edit date to find the most recent edit. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: do we still have a Hidden Features question? This sure belongs there. Had no idea that thing was clickable.

Comment: @KateGregory ...wait, that's clickable? *\*clicks\** I had no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's already there, in the right sidebar, just under the tag list. (Except for questions with no answers; so if it's not there, just check the question).

> [image: my bad freehand circle]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I've always avoided the right-hand side of the screen, I guess Facebook is to blame.

Answer (score 5):

[image: last activity]                                              ...which is over there, in the sidebar[image: arrow]

Like all times on the network, you can hover for a more specific UTC timestamp if you need that level of granulairty.

Comment: -1, your arrow is a bit off... it's a bit further "up".

Comment: +1 for Hover tip, also found out that I can click the Activity link to go to the question/answer that was edited last.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking, but you always have the *Active* info in the top right the corner. And you always have the option of sorting the answers by date.

So as I understand your question, this is already implemented.